# Delay slide up on sub menu

Tags: jquery, hide, delay, slideup

I am trying to delay a sub-menu from sliding up when its not being hovered on. Can't seem to get it to work with this jquery at all. thinking css is over riding? it says when the menu should appear and disappear basically. JS fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/gQ3Cv/5/

```
 $("#primary-nav ul li ul").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).parent(".submenu").show()                                               
});
$("#primary-nav ul li ul").mouseout(function(){
         $(this).parent(".submenu").delay(1500).slideUp(300)                                                
});
```

Comment: Some HTML would be helpful in recreating your problem.

Comment: could you present a jsfiddle?

Comment: Try posting your example on http://jsfiddle.net/ so we have something to go by

Comment: sorry about that, just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a delayed reaction of sorts try

```
var myDelay = 1500;
$("#primary-nav ul li ul").mouseover(function(){
        var elem = $(this).parent(".submenu");
        setTimeout(function(){elem.show();}, myDelay);                                            
});
$("#primary-nav ul li ul").mouseout(function(){
        var elem = $(this).parent(".submenu");
        setTimeout(function(){elem.slideUp(300).hide();}, myDelay);                                         
});
```

of course I am just typing this out without testing the notion. But this would be my first attempt at the least, may require a bit of play to work just right. Of course this may cause an adverse and undesired reaction due to the delay. But I dunno for sure.

Comment: didn't seem to work. The issue isn't getting the function to run, I applied it to a different element and it worked fine, it's just getting it to run on the section that I need it...

Comment: ahh my confusion then. The problem may be then, your choice of parent instead of parents, as well as what your selector for your parent/parents is defined as. If you could provide the HTML in your post specific to your javascript here we may be able to help, or better yet include it in the post and make a jsfiddle.net version of it and share that link here with us as well

Comment: I can post the link to the live issue so you can see what is going on. It's in WordPress, so it's a lot to copy over, and a lot of unnecessary stuff in there. www.kyrusmobile.com